# How to limit number of characters to paste in the text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to limit the number of characters to be pasted in a multiline textbox.

Let's say this is my string to be pasted in the textbox:

> Good day Ladies and Gents!
>   
>   I just want to know

If this is possible, please help.

The rule is maximum characters PER LINE is 10, Maximum ROWS is 2. Applying the rule, pasted text should only be like this:

> Good day L
>   
>   I just wan

Comment: do you want to allow user to use short keys `Ctrl + V`?

Comment: yes, any form of paste (CTRL + V, right-click+paste, SHIFT + INSERT) is allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not automatic what to do this.  You'll need to handle the `TextChanged` event on the text box and manually parse the changed text to limit it to the format required.

```
private const int MaxCharsPerRow = 10;
private const int MaxLines = 2;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string[] lines = textBox1.Lines;
    var newLines = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length && i < MaxLines; i++) {
        newLines.Add(lines[i].Substring(0, Math.Min(lines[i].Length, MaxCharsPerRow)));
    }
    textBox1.Lines = newLines.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the message `WM_PASTE` (sent to your `TextBox`) to process yourself:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    int maxLine = 2;
    int maxChars = 10;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x302)//WM_PASTE
        {
            string s = Clipboard.GetText();
            string[] lines = s.Split('\n');
            s = "";
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                s += (line.Length > maxChars ? line.Substring(0, maxChars) : line) + "\r\n";
                if (++i == maxLine) break;
            }
            if(i > 0) SelectedText = s.Substring(0,s.Length - 2);//strip off the last \r\n
            return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but changing control(or textbox) will be much of a pain to me...

Comment: @JackFrost not really. Just add a separate class in your project. You can reuse this class. This is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by the following way. Set `maximum length` of the text box as 22

```
textBox1.MaxLength = 22;
```

In the text change event do the following

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (textBox1.Text.Length == 10)
     {
           textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
     }
}
```

This will automatically enters to next line after 10 characters

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but you see, I already have a restriction regarding that matter (when user is trying to input normally like NOT pasting). My problem now is how to capture the paste...

Comment: @Nitesh - you solution doesn't work in the case of pasting because when pasting the text's length goes from 0 immediately to the size of the of the pasted it text.  It is never exactly 10 so the adding of the new line never occurs.  Nor does it work if the user types in 2 character, hits enter, then types 2 characters and hits enter.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you work on the clipboard data to achieve this. Below is a small example .

```
String clipboardText = Clipbard.GetText( );

// MAXPASTELENGTH - max length allowed by your program

if(clipboardText.Length > MAXPASTELENGTH)
{

   Clipboard.Clear(); 

   String newClipboardText = clipboardText.Substring(0, MAXPASTELENGTH);

   // set the new clipboard data to the max length 
   SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)newClipboardText );

}
```

Now paste the data whereever you like , the data shall be trimmed to the maximum length allowed by your program .

Answer (score -2):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            textBox1.MaxLength = 10;
            //MessageBox.Show("maksimal 10 karakter");
        }
    }
```

Comment: How does this help better than the other solutions already given?